# linux tomcat server died after i moved new class file

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos7

`
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/alpha] startup failed due to previous errors

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/alpha] is completed
`

i was moving new project's controller class file to old project.

the controller class has autowired service class file but i didn't move it.

tomcat tried reload, got an error and showed 404 error.

i deleted the controller file but tomcat doesnt try reload and catalina showed upper's error.

how can i automatically reload tomcat without restart tomcat?

Comment: *startup failed due to previous errors* - go back in the log and find the previous errors

Comment: it's because the controller class has autowired service class file but i didn't move it. what i want to know is how to reload tomcat without restart tomcat automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat by default observes an application's `WEB-INF/web.xml`

If you `touch` that file, chances are that tomcat attempts another start of that app.

But naturally, you'll have to fix your app first, and hopefully you haven't changed the default

Another alternative is to completely remove your webapp from tomcat's `webapps` directory, and after a short while move it back.

Comment: context still doesn't reload. how can i manually reload context?